# php changing div using DOMDocument but doesn't update page

Tags: php, dom, html

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm getting the right nodeValue for what I want. It's just not updating when the php script is done. Here's the code:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    //suppress HTML5 and other errors
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($pageURL);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $divContent = $xpath->query("//*[@id='resultStats']/p")->item(0);
    $newText = new DOMText("100 results");
    var_dump($divContent->nodeValue); //returns old test value "400 results" which is correct
    $divContent->removeChild($divContent->firstChild);
    $divContent->appendChild($newText);
    var_dump($divContent->localName); //"p" because i got it from <p> in resultStats
    var_dump($divContent->textContent); //"100 results"
    var_dump($divContent->nodeValue); //"100 results"
```

more of the HTML that is around it

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="resultStats span3 offset1" id="resultStats">
      <p>400 results found.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="span12">
         <div class="row">
              <div class="span6 offset1">
                  <?php
                         if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
                        //code from above that is executing every time from tests
                         }
                  ?>
               </div>
               <div class="span5">
                  span5
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I do dom->save it rewrites everything (even php code) so I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: it doesn't update what page?

Comment: You're showing us code that appears to work. You're not showing us the rest. Having preformed this operation with DomDocument, what do you do with the result?

Comment: @PatrickEvans the page I'm executing the php script in

Comment: for the html file you are manipulating to show up on the page you have to echo/print it out, `echo $dom->saveHTML()` or `echo $dom->saveHTML($divContent)` if you are only wanting to output the contents of `$divContent`

Comment: @PatrickEvans that seems to work, but it just replaces my php code with the whole html file again so providing a nested html file. I get null pointers if I try to use loadHTML($pageUrl) instead of loadHTMLFile($pageURL) as well.

Comment: @MikeW just update the resultStats div with number of results after I get it from the PHP script.

Comment: @PatrickEvans `echo $dom->saveHTML($divContent)` doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're using `DOMDocument` for this. Can't you just do this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="resultStats span3 offset1" id="resultStats">

<?php

  // get new result count somehow in $resultCount

  echo '<p>'.$resultCount.' results found</p>';
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, because I execute the queries and display stuff after that div.

Comment: If you've already emitted the code for this `<div>` then you can't change it in PHP later with DOMDocument. You should look at re-ordering your code to execute the queries first and generate the output later.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that you could. I reordered my code already though and got what I wanted.